# Is CType() ever the preferred option?

Tags: coding-standards, vb.net

Is there any time `CType()` is the proper option over other methods? I did plenty of thinking on this myself, but wanted to put the question in hopes there would be answer to my question so I can put the question to rest in my workplace.

My idea is that `CType()` should never be used.  But others seem to think it's still around for something other than backward-compatibility.  So is there still a use for it?

A big problem is that many people don't seem to understand the difference between Casting and Converting.

### Converting Vs Casting

This was one such line of code:

```
With objZipFile.GetEnumerator()
    While .MoveNext
        objZipEntry = CType(.Current, ZipEntry)
        … all this work is done with the objZipEntry
    End While
End With
```

If my buddy ever reads this, he'll be like, "MY CODE!!!!" lol.  Yes, this is your code.  And as I discussed with him, .Current is an enumeration of objZipFile, but its type is ZipEntry.  So why is he "Converting" with `CType()`, when what he's really doing here is Casting.  He should be using `DirectCast(.Current, ZipEntry)`.

So the proper way to Cast something is to use `DirectCast()`.  But this isn't a discussion about `DirectCast()`.  The point here is that `CType()` Should certainly not be used to Cast, it's a Conversion tool, so let's talk more about Converting.

### To CType() or Not To CType(), I don't think so

In the simplistic example, I have a string `"123"`, and I want the string to be converted to an Integer.  So many times, you see something like this:

```
Dim result as Integer = 0
result = CType("123", Integer)
```

Great!  It Works!  Then what is the difference between that and this:

```
Dim result as Integer = 0
result = Integer.Parse("123")
```

Well, with that exact example, the difference is that `CType()` took more resources to run.  If I gave you two clear drinks and told you one had a health rating of 10, and the other of 9.  You don't choose the 9 on principle that it isn't that much less healthy, you choose the dam 10.  Also, the `Integer.Parse` line is a couple characters of less typing.

Okay, but what if your input isn't "123"?  What if the input is "UrMom"?  I hear `CType()` won't break... but as far as I know, that isn't true.  `CType()` breaks just as much as `Type.Parse()`.  I'd like some arguments on that.  Though an argument supporting `CType()`'s resilience alone isn't reason enough to use `CType()`.

On the other hand, we have this option in the `Type`-Class:

```
Dim MyInt As Integer = 0
Dim TryInt As Integer = 0
If Integer.TryParse("54", TryInt) Then
    MyInt = TryInt 
Else
    'Handle it appropriately 
End If
```

Not only are we parsing the data, but if it doesn't parse, we are handling it correctly.  Which is a much better option that throwing a `Try/Catch` around bad code and letting it break before handling its failure in the `Catch/Finally`.

Keep in mind, there may be multiple different ways to cast and convert, but the main purpose of this question is to prove or disprove that `CType()` simply shouldn't be used.

My main argument is this... The only arguments I've seen that support the use of `CType()` are those that say `CType()` won't break if passed bad data, or that `CType()` is better if you are unsure of the data going in.  In response to that I say Pish-Posh.  Rethink your code, place conditionals, and know what you're wanting to use the item for.  If something happens that you weren't expecting, handle it correctly.

So is there any time `CType()` is the proper option over other methods? Please provide examples.

Comment: Assuming you're being light and sarcastic: Lol, thanks Jeff.  In case you aren't... If nothing else mattered (which a lot more does), I'd obviously choose 2 less characters than otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification in your edit, but you should review this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: Microsoft originally suggested `DirectCast` was a back-end construct that you don't need to know about -- just use `CType`. But everyone who understood the difference used `DirectCast` when casting. The point about `CType` is that it can try both conversion and casting, if required. So when you really don't know what could be in an `Object` you might just use `CType` to allow the best possible chance of getting valid data rather than an exception.

Comment: @MarkHurd  That is a huge proponent response for `CType`, so I'm glad you brought it up.  A co-worker made this same argument.  I ended up refactoring his "unknown items" into a set of classes following an interface and used dependency injection.  I can't think of a time that you might have a Conversion Or Casting, and not know which.  That has to be some messy stuff.  I'd love to see a legit SOLID OO example of that, seriously.

Comment: How is my question not clear? `CType` Is a method with similar use to Parsing Methods and less similar to Casting Methods. I asked, "Is there any time `CType()` is the proper option over other methods? Please provide examples." I need fellow engineers to give examples when `CType` is preferred over other options for readability, maintainability, performance, or other objective reasons. I don't care if nobody can answer my question, or if the answer is just "Never" but it certainly shouldn't be closed or on-hold. This relates to programming practices, not coding, and seems perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*Edit: This question/answer pair were during a C++/C# developer's short stint in the confusing world of Visual Basic.  It turns out that the proper answer is: Don't use Visual Basic. At this time, the best support for `CType()` is a VB6 to early .NET support document from 2003. EndEdit*

After allowing this question to live online for a while, and also working with peers on research and usage regarding Casting and Converting, the answer has become clear.

The question was: Is there any time `CType()` is the proper option over other methods?

The answer is: No.  From this point on, never use `CType()`.

The only argument is: "What if you don't know the type you're casting?"

The counter argment to that is: Then refactor your program, be more explicit with your intentions, and perhaps stop using weak-typed objects, "strong-typed" datasets, or datasets in general.

Comment: -1 "From this point on, never use CType()." There is always an exception to every rule. Metaprogramming and other edge cases often dictate that while there are best practices, there are always places where obscure, poor performance functions are necessary.

Comment: Although I will say good job on the diligence to the question :)

Comment: So undo the -1 and create an answer to the question.  I literally put CType() in the same realm as GoTo (for C#/VB).  Some devs might say there's always an exception to the rule, but if I see GoTo in code in any business I work with, I'd rip the developer a new one.  Same now with CType() when .Net has alternatives that are less resource intensive and more explicit for intention.  Also, I did say "From this point on", meaning nobody expects legacy junk code to be completely refactored if you have the issue of bad data typing or something.

Comment: Actually the recommendation from Microsoft is exactly the opposite: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa289509 See `Conversion Functions, CType, DirectCast, and System.Convert` Section

Comment: @Ampt: If metaprogramming is an "edge case", you're doing it wrong. :P

Comment: Thanks for the VB6 to Early .NET Document from 2003.  The only support in that document says to use CType if you need implicit coercion.  The question then becomes: In what kind of hacky code do you need implicit coercion?  The article's argument is converting Double to Int.  Use Math.Floor or something for that.

Comment: @MasonWheeler if anything close to decent performance is an "edge case", you're doing it wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

CType is often useful when dealing with legacy code and database records -- where the "correct" field can potentially be of more than one type.  For instance a date or a date string.  Refacoring this can be time consuming and error prone, particularly when the results are from stored procedures and are also used by reports.

Comment: jmoreno! Familiar face. Is it not true that; Even if you have no clue what an incoming type is, you do know what you plan to do with it. In this example, you plan to use it as a Date, and that's all that matters. Other than changing `CType(object, Date)` to `Date.Parse(object)`, you may need to check if you're catching `CType`-Specific exceptions, which would be awkward because that means you're expecting failures and would be better off with `Date.TryParse()` anyway.

Comment: Also... I believe there's an article somewhere that says `Ctype("3:45", Date)` properly parses `3:45`, whereas `Date.Parse("3:45")` also adds the current date. I'd say that breaks explicit development. If you convert a string to a Date, it should be a Date. If you want to parse a TimeSpan, you should use `TimeSpan.Parse("3:45")`.  In this sense, `CType` is doing something unintuitive.

Comment: Lastly, lol... sorry I type a lot.  I do think that just because `CType` exists in Legacy code, doesn't merit re-factoring or changing it.  Unless it is used millions of times across multiple projects daily, it won't be causing enough slowdown to merit refactor.  But in future projects, it would be discouraged unless an answer comes up with a good reason otherwise, which I sorta hope happens.

Comment: @Suamere: there is no Date.Parse(object).  And I have seen differences between what the various type conversions output when dealing with dates-- I wouldn't change from one to the other unless I fully understood what was being passed and what was being returned.

Comment: Well put.  I would have added `.ToString`. And while most of the question involves *choosing* `CType` over other options (such as in future development)... I would actually be happy to see an example in legacy code where *keeping* `CType` over changing to a different option is the best choice. I'm guessing that once a coder "fully understand[s] what's being passed and what [is] being returned", though, it would become clear that `CType` isn't the best option.  Again, I'd love to find an example.